# Can't adapt some code to give 3 column grid

Tags: html, css, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to reproduce this 3 column grid http://romeavenue.com/en/2/Tours-Of-Italy but i can't get it to work.  All i get is a 2 column grid and i can't work out why - see http://eternalcitytours.com/en/2/Tours-Of-Italy

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?? PS sites should be responsive to change with viewport.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1):

`Isotope` calculates the number of columns, based on the width of the parent element.  When calculating the width, you also have to bear in mind padding and margin, as part of the [box-model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model).

Simply changing `.feature` to have a width of `1000px` gives you three columns:

```
feature {
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Obviously, you'll have to do a bit of adjustment of the rest of the layout to make it work correctly, but that should give you a start.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I did as you suggested and it looks find on my laptop.  However when i look at it on my iphone the colums are aligned to far to the right.  How do u adjust it so that on one device e.g. a laptop all margins and padding is one thing and on another device e.g. an iphone, they are different?

Comment: Honestly, that belongs in a completely different question. However, you are looking for `CSS media queries`. With these, you can select different styles based upon viewport width.

Comment: If this answered your question, please select the answer as correct, in order to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is no code available and i cannot yet comment, my first guess would be that the container hasn't got enough width for 3 columns.